# Como calcular 2^n e (2^n)+1 em java?

Tags: java, loop, método

Estou a fazer um trabalho no qual tenho que fazer alguns cálculos com pilhas e preciso de fazer testes para potências de dois e potências de dois mais um, ou seja 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 16, 17, etc.

A parte das potências de dois faz-se facilmente, mas como faço um loop ou um ciclo para as potências de dois mais um?

Comment: Você tem que fazer até qual potência?

Comment: @jbueno a potência é até à que quiser. Estou a faze basicamente um método em que o utilizador introduz o valor da potência máximo que quer os testes. Por exemplo, se o utilizador puser 5, os testes vão ser feitos até (2^5)+1, ou seja vai fazer testes a 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,16,17,32,33

Comment: @jbueno era isso mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É simples, só fazer o cálculo da potência e depois adicionar 1.

Como não há mais detalhes segue abaixo. O código calcula todas as potências de 2 e as potências de 2 somados com 1.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Digite um número: ");
int numeroEscolhido = input.nextInt(); //número digitado pelo usuário

for(int i = 0; i <= numeroEscolhido; i++){
    int potenciaDe2 = (int)Math.pow(2, i);

    System.out.println(String.format("(2^%s): %s | (2^%s)+1: %s", i, potenciaDe2, i, potenciaDe2 + 1));
}
```

Entrando com o número **5**, a saída será:

> ```
> (2^0): 1 | (2^0)+1: 2  
> (2^1): 2 | (2^1)+1: 3  
> (2^2): 4 | (2^2)+1: 5  
> (2^3): 8 | (2^3)+1: 9  
> (2^4): 16 | (2^4)+1: 17  
> (2^5): 32 | (2^5)+1: 33
> ```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/HIXE/2)