# Como optimizar um loop de potências de 2^n e (2^n)+1 em java?

Tags: java, loop, método

Boas,

Tou a fazer um trabalho em que tenho que fazer testes em stacks, e os testes têm que ser feitos quando faço push e pop de potências de 2 e potências de 2 mais um (1,2,3,4,5,8,9,16,17, etc...)
Tenho algum código feito:

```
 public static void testsForLinkedLists(int maxPowerOf,
        int intendedRepeats, String excelFile,
         IntToDoubleFunction pushMethod, IntToDoubleFunction  popMethod) {


        ArrayList<Double> listOfPushTimes = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> listOfPopTimes = new ArrayList<Double>();


        double maxPush = 0;
        double minPush = 100;
        double maxPop = 0;
        double minPop = 100;
        double medianPush = 0;
        double medianPop = 0;
        double sumPush = 0;
        double sumPop = 0;
        double averagePush = 0;
        double averagePop = 0;



        int total = 0;
        int excelLine = 1;
        //int actualPowerOf = 0;
        for (int actualPowerOf = 0; actualPowerOf < maxPowerOf; actualPowerOf++) {

            listOfPushTimes.clear();
            listOfPopTimes.clear();
            //actualPowerOf++;
            maxPush = 0;
            minPush = 100;
            maxPop = 0;
            minPop = 100;
            medianPush = 0;
            medianPop = 0;
            sumPush = 0;
            sumPop = 0;
            averagePush = 0;
            averagePop = 0;
            total = 0;
            int powerOf2 = (int)Math.pow(2, actualPowerOf);
            for (int i = 0; i < intendedRepeats; i++) {

                double timetopush = pushMethod.applyAsDouble(powerOf2);
                listOfPushTimes.add(timetopush);
                sumPush = sumPush + timetopush;
                if (timetopush > maxPush) {
                    maxPush = timetopush;
                }
                if (timetopush < minPush) {
                    minPush = timetopush;
                }
                double timetopop = pushMethod.applyAsDouble(powerOf2);
                listOfPopTimes.add(timetopop);
                sumPop = sumPop + timetopop;
                if (timetopop > maxPop) {
                    maxPop = timetopop;
                }
                if (timetopop < minPop) {
                    minPop = timetopop;
                }
                total++;
            }
            averagePush = sumPush / total;
            averagePop = sumPop / total;
            medianPush = measuring_tools.medianOf(listOfPushTimes);
            medianPop = measuring_tools.medianOf(listOfPopTimes);

}
```

O meu objetivo é calcular a primeira potência e fazer testes, carregar a potência seguinte e fazer os respetivos testes ... até chegar ao maxPowerOf que o utilizador introduziu. Se o Utilizador pôe 4, vão ser feitos testes até (2^4)+1, ou seja 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,16,17

O problema é que desta forma, fico com dois números dois(2^0+1 e o 2^1) e ainda tenho que repetir montes de código para fazer os testes que são iguais tanto para potências de dois como para potência de dois mais um. O ideal seria, ter um ciclo com os testes lá dentro em que o ciclo ia mudando o valor para o desejado por mim(potências de dois e dois mais um). O ideal talvez seria ter um ciclo dentro de outro ciclo

Existe alguma forma de optimizar este código para não repetir o número 2 e para não ter que repetir o código dos testes todo?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como calcular 2^n e (2^n)+1 em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198009/28595)

Comment: @diegofm fui eu que coloquei essa questão e agora fiz esta que está relacionada mas é diferente

Comment: Eu sei, por isso que relacionei.

Comment: Não é só iniciar o indice por 1? `for (int i = 1; i <= maxPowerOf; i++)`

Comment: @diegofm Aí come o primeiro resultado. É só não fazer o segundo caso quando o expoente for zero, pode responder isso.

Comment: Não, porque ai não dá o 2^0=1

Comment: @jbueno vê o meu edit, talvez ajude

Comment: @user6273698 Nem pensar que eu vou parar pra ler esse amontado gigante de código. Por favor, tente ser mais sucinto.

Comment: @jbueno editado, a unica coisa que é preciso ver é o ciclo for